# A different Crack the Code puzzle

Tags: word, no-computers, mastermind

This is a different Crack the Code and get the word puzzle. Here, instead of letters, actual words are hidden.

The final word is a 7 letter famous person. That word consists of several words. I only considered 2 or more letter words formed with consecutive letters only.

For Example COPING : COP, PI, PIN, IN, PING are the words. "I" being a single letter word and COIN being a non continuous word is not considered.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's

> (Nelson) Mandela

Hidden words:

> **adamant**: 'man', 'an' and 'ma' in the wrong position 
>  **islands**: 'and', 'an' and 'la' in the wrong position
>  **cantala**: 'an' and 'la' in the correct positions
>  **advised**: none